# What's the difference between { color: inherit } vs { color: currentColor }?

Tags: css

Please see this minimum example

```css
.inherit {
  color: red;
}
.inherit p {
  color: inherit;
}

.currentColor {
  color: red;
}
.currentColor p {
  color: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<div class="inherit">
  <p>inherit</p>
</div>

<div class="currentColor">
  <p>currentColor</p>
</div>
```

These two are resulting in the same.

Is there any difference when using `currentColor` in the `color` property when I can just use `inherit`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`inherit` means that the value used by the parent is used.

`currentColor` follows ***closest*** color property value,

#### Example 1

this divs border-color and box-shadow color will be red. Because currentColor follows closest color property value.

```css
div { 
  color: red; 
  border: 5px solid currentColor;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px solid currentColor;
}
```

#### Example 2

this divs border-color and box-shadow color will be blue. Because the closest color property value is defined in the body and its blue.

```css
body {
  color: blue;
}

body > div { 
  border: 5px solid currentColor;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px solid currentColor;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, it just explains how currentColor works.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference:

> In the 'color' property, the used value of 'currentcolor' is the inherited value.

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#resolving-other-colors

Answer (score 0):

the currentColor keyword is used to make properties of an element, or child elements of an element, inherit the color set by the element's color property. It therefore acts as the inherit value to allow inheritance of a color that would otherwise not be inherited by a property or child element